# Save image in library

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I have to save image in library in iPhone and iPad so here is the code for it

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

but the problem is I want to save image with subview means what in UIImageView have some other view like UILabel and UIImageView so how can I save image with all the subviews.

Screenshot is the way but in that the screen size is fix but i want to actual size of image what user capture.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible if you do it like this

```
// Take a UIView of the image size
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width,img.size.height)];
UIImageVIew *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:view.frame];
[imgView setImage:img];
[view addSubview:imgView];// after this give the positioning of your labels in the view and then perform this operation.

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code will surely work but the positioning of your labels will move from where you actually placed them if you are not able to give the correct frame.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: this is work but it stil capture the current screen 320x460 but i need to capture full size of image which is captured by camera iPhone 4s so it's size is big. is there any other way to capture full size image..